# Schema hasn't been registered for model. Mongodb>Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi my code is shown below:

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Schema=mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId=Schema.ObjectId;

var BlogPost= new Schema({
    author:ObjectId,
    title:String,
    body:String,
    date:Date
    });

var myModel =mongoose.model('BlogPost','BlogPost');
console.log(myModel);
```

Need advise. I am always getting this exception.

```
  500 MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "BlogPost".<br/>Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `mongoose.model` in a wrong way. You should pass a schema object object, but you're passing `'BlogPost'` string instead. Try the following code:

```
var BlogPost= new Schema({
  author: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  body: String,
  date: Date
});

var myModel = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost); // BlogPost is an object here
```

After that mongoose will create `blogposts` colection (lowercased and pluralized) in `mongodb://localhost/test` database. If you want to change collection name corresponding to your model, pass it as a thirs parameter:

```
var myModel = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost, 'BlogPost');
```